I have installed buildkit, and I can run the deamon manually. I want to manage it with systemd instead, is this possible?
Installed with this:
tar -C ~/.local/bin/ -xzf /tmp/nerdctl.tar.gz --strip-components 1 bin/buildkitd bin/buildctl

Run the deamon with this:
sudo $(which buildkitd) &

which buildkitd returns this: /home/<username>/.local/bin/buildkitd
What file should I start using systemd?
Currently start containerd with
sudo systemctl enable containerd
sudo systemctl start containerd

Using 24.04 LTS WSL 2

What is the version of Ubuntu you are using?

24.04 LTS WSL 2 @DavidDE
